# JSON.stringify() only allows one value parameter. How do I add more parameters to be stringified under one brace?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
http.get(options, function(res){
            fs.appendFile('log.txt', JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, 4));
})
```

I have a question regarding the `JSON.stringify()` function.

I've learned that simply using the `res.headers` does *not* in fact output to JSON format.

At the moment, I am restricted to only being able to use one res.xxxxx method within JSON.stringify(). The piece of code in question is pasted above. How am I able to use more than one value? At the moment, I can only put in `res.headers` into the `value` parameter. I would also like to use `res.statusCode` and my own objects, all stringified under one brace {}.

The parameters of JSON.Stringify is as follows: `JSON.stringify(value, [replacer], [space]);`

Comment: What's the content of `res.headers`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*all stringified under one brace*"?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yes, I know. Using `res.headers` itself doesn't output to JSON. Using JSON.stringify() does. My conundrum is that JSON.stringify() only allows one parameter. I am wondering if there is a work-around to that.
@T.J.Crowder They are simply HTTP response headers with things like "date" "server" "x-powered-by" "x-aspnet-version" "location" etc

Comment: `JSON.stringify(value, [replacer], [space]);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to create a new js object and put res.headers into it.

```
var obj = {};
obj.headers = res.headers;
obj.somethingelse = somethingelse;
var string = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much, my good friend. Can't believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 4):

JSON is always a single value. So the output out `JSON.stringify` can always only be a single value. It would make sense to have the input be a single value too. This is like asking *why can't my function return two things?* You can make it return some composite value, but that means you're still returning a single (composite) value. The solution here is the same, compose your input.

```
var reply = {
    code: res.statusCode,
    headers: parse_http_headers(res.headers),
    etc: /* etc */
};
log(JSON.stringify(reply));
```

Note that you must write `parse_http_headers` yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain the downvote? mooreds beat me to it by 15 seconds, hardly a reason for a downvote I think.

Answer (score 3):

You could always add the extra things you want to the headers object...

```
res.headers.statusCode = res.statusCode
JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, 4);
```

I don't know if there are any bad side effects if you mutate the `res` object in node. You might want to consider creating a shallow copy of the headers object if you are worried about that.

Answer (score 2):

You could as well stringify more than only the `headers` part of your object:

```
JSON.stringify(res, …)
```

If you want to stringify only certain parts of your object, you can

- filter them with the `replacer` function,
- `delete` everything else before,
- or build a new object to be stringified:

  ```
  JSON.stringify({
      heads: res.headers,
      …
  }, …)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to flatten several objects, you can use this function.

```
function merge() {
  var out = {};
  insert = function(e) {
    for (var i in e) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, i))
          out[i] = e[i];
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    insert(arguments[i]);  
  }

  return out; 
}

var a = {'a': 'aa'};
var b = {'b': 'bb', 'bbb': 'bbbb'};
var c = {'c': 'cc'};


var combined = merge(a,b,c);
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` has some known pitfalls. Try flattening this object: `{ hasOwnProperty: function () { return false; }, foo: "bar" }`. The solution is to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(..)`